# If statement conditions unmet and yet program gets stuck

Tags: c, cs50

Basically the conditions are unmet and yet the program will not proceed from the main if statement into the else statement. I'll give the gist of it, a tl;dr version upfront and the full version below that.

tl;dr version:

```
a = 1;
b = 2;
c = 3;

if(a == 1)
{
    if(b == 1 && c == 1)
    do x;

    if(b == 2 && c == 2)
    do y;

    if(b == 3 && c == 3)
    do z;
}
else
printf("Invalid\n");
```

Basically none of the smaller if statement conditions are met and the program should proceed to the else statement and print "Invalid", but it won't. It just does nothing. For the actual program, see:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int checksum = 10;
int j = 16;
long first = 5;
long second = 6;

int main(void)
{
    checksum %= 10;
    if(checksum == 0)
    {
        if(j == 15 && first == 3 && (second == 4 || second == 7))
        printf("AMEX\n");

        if(j == 16 && first == 5 && (second == 1 || second == 2 || second == 3 || second == 4 || second == 5))
        printf("MASTERCARD\n");

        if((j == 16 || j == 13) && first == 4)
        printf("VISA\n");
    }
    else
    printf("INVALID\n");
}
```

Comment: `else` is only related to the outermost `if` whose condition is true.

Comment: An `else` is associated with a single `if` statement: here the `if (a==1)` , and not any of the other `if ` statements.

Comment: You need `else if`. Check your favourite C programming book.

Comment: You should indent your code properly

Comment: @Jabberwocky you mean the printf lines?

Comment: @ILoveYeezis yes

Comment: @Jabberwocky Is it bad? I thought it looks more comprehensible like this.

Comment: @ILoveYeezis not it doesn't. Indentation should be consistent.

Comment: Another approach is "early exit"  If you have a block of code that could return one of many values, you can write each `if` statement to `return <some value>;` and then you avoid the need for many `else if` clauses.  It doesn't change the logical processing, but it does make the code easier to add or remove future return values.  The "default" value is returned at the end of the block.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Alright, will do, thanks.

Comment: @EdwinBuck yes, thanks. I thought about it but I'm such a novice I haven't learned the return values yet.

Comment: @ILoveYeezis Not a problem at all.  We all start at the same place.  I provided a clear example to let you see how you can do "exit early".  "Exit early" approaches shouldn't be used for everything; and the "early" isn't just decoration on the word "exit".  If you "exit" in the middle or late, the code gets more confusing.  The approach works best for functions, but in a small enough "main" program it will work fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program prints "INVALID" only when the bigger if statement is unmet. You need to change your code by adding another **else** associated with the smaller if statement conditions, as follow:

```
#include <cs50.h>    
#include <stdio.h>
    
    int checksum = 10;
    int j = 16;
    long first = 5;
    long second = 6;
    
    int main(void)
    {
        checksum %= 10;
        if(checksum == 0)
        {
            if(j == 15 && first == 3 && (second == 4 || second == 7))
                printf("AMEX\n");
    
            else if(j == 16 && first == 5 && (second == 1 || second == 2 || second == 3 || second == 4 || second == 5))
                printf("MASTERCARD\n");
    
            else if((j == 16 || j == 13) && first == 4)
                printf("VISA\n");
    
            else printf("INVALID\n");
        }
        else
            printf("INVALID\n");
    }
```

Hope it could be helpful,

Giovanni Pachera

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to "make the code look a little cleaner" you can use a programming pattern called "exit early."  The basic idea is that for each "correct" answer, you return the value.  Since you are not using functions yet, your program will have to exit early; but, typically a function returns the "correct" value instead of the program returning if it succeeded / failed.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int checksum = 10;
int j = 16;
long first = 5;
long second = 6;

int main(void) {
    checksum %= 10;
    if(checksum == 0 && j == 15 && first = 3 && (second == 4 || second == 7) {
        printf("AMEX\n");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    if (checksum == 0 && j == 16 && first == 5 && (second == 1 || second == 2 || second == 3 || second == 4 || second == 5))
        printf("MASTERCARD\n");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    if (checksum == 0 && (j == 16 || j == 13) && first == 4)
        printf("VISA\n");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    printf("INVALID\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

The `int` in `int main(void) {` is the program's return code.  It is sent back to the terminal so a person can tell if the program ran correctly or encountered an error.  `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are C constants, defined in (I think `<stdlib.h>`).

Also, consider getting into the habit of using `int main(int argc, char* argv)` over `int main(void)`.  Even if you don't use the argument parameters right away, it is the one way to type the `main` function that you'll never have to update.